# PUT method returns 415 instead of 405 on method supporting only POST

Tags: java, spring, methods, controller, http-method

I am trying to do the upload of a file according to this example : 
[Spring Boot file upload](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

But when I try to do a PUT ( just for testing purposes ) on this method that allows only POST, i received a 415 Unsupported Media Type, instead of a 405.

If I try to do a POST, it works fine.

If I switch them, putting PUT on the method and doing a request with POST, it gives  the correct code : 405 . 
Isn't this behavior strange?

LE :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.POST,
      produces = "application/json")
  public ResponseEntity<Object> upload(
    @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name,
    @RequestParam(value = "batchFile", required = true) MultipartFile file) 

{
```

Comment: please provide actual code for better understanding

Comment: I have added the code sample.

Comment: file upload isn't doable with PUT, the `MultipartResolver`s already block the request if it is non-post. Also how do you do a PUT as a browsers form (no JS) only support GET and POST.

Comment: I'm doing the request from Postman.

Comment: If MultipartResolver blocked this method, why isn't the returned code 405 ?

Comment: Well actually it isn't blocking it it isn't parsing the request. So you now receive a multipart request, which cannot be handled by spring itself (it isn't wrapped in a `MultipartRequest` which knows how to obtain the request parameters). So it even fails before it even reaches the controller. The second one is detected as a multipart request and passed on to the controller, but a POST cannot be handled by a PUT.

Comment: So wrapping the request as a MultipartRequest will do the trick ? This is my understanding. If so, how can this be achieved?